# expo-auth-session/providers/google Google.useAuthRequest

Tags: react-native, expo, google-oauth

I have a problem with the implementation of Google Auth within a React Native app managed with Expo.
When I try to login, the response does not contain an IdToken or the information of the user and I don't understand why...

Here is my code :

```jsx
 import * as Google from 'expo-auth-session/providers/google';
 
 const [request1, response1, promptAsync1] = Google.useAuthRequest({
    expoClientId: 'my-expo-id',
    iosClientId: 'my-ios-id',
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (response1?.type === 'success') {
      const { authentication } = response1;
    }
  }, [response]);

  console.log('reponse', response1)
  
  return (
  <View>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => promptAsync1()}>
            <Text style={styles.connexionText}>Connect with Google</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
  
  )
```

And here is the response :

```json
reponse Object {
  "authentication": TokenResponse {
    "accessToken": "ya29.a0AfH6SMAEdPx5RcQP57rtdr4gV8GxFD1VSLAjovOce5X1yP-a2S6inLcSHF3KlxqmbKt0Cl6Catuyuua9Jz0rtV5psUUqWWX_QT32rXJwt9LTQywQaOzyy4cwspbOLm6W063w27f7NRiizC9RBg69-Yh09OhN",
    "expiresIn": "3599",
   ** "idToken": undefined, **
    "issuedAt": 1617701320,
    ** "refreshToken": undefined, **
    "scope": "email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "state": "RwgjNwizdQ",
    "tokenType": "Bearer",
  },
  "error": null,
  "errorCode": null,
  "params": Object {
    "access_token": "ya29.a0AfH6SMAEdPx5RcQP57rtdr4gV8GxFD1VSLAjovOce5X1yP-a2S6inLcSHF3KlxqmbKt0Cl6Catuyuua9Jz0rtV5psUUqWWX_QT32rXJwt9LTQywQaOzyy4cwspbOLm6W063w27f7NRiizC9RBg69-Yh09OhN",
    "authuser": "0",
    "exp://172.20.10.3:19000/--/expo-auth-session": "",
    "expires_in": "3599",
    "prompt": "none",
    "scope": "email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "state": "RwgjNwizdQ",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
  },
  "type": "success",
  "url": "exp://172.20.10.3:19000/--/expo-auth-session#state=RwgjNwizdQ&access_token=ya29.a0AfH6SMAEdPx5RcQP57rtdr4gV8GxFD1VSLAjovOce5X1yP-a2S6inLcSHF3KlxqmbKt0Cl6Catuyuua9Jz0rtV5psUUqWWX
_QT32rXJwt9LTQywQaOzyy4cwspbOLm6W063w27f7NRiizC9RBg69-Yh09OhN&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3599&scope=email%20profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile%20openid%20https:/
/www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email&authuser=0&prompt=none",
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your help !

Comment: Yeah and the worst part is the older method of authenticating with google does provide the idToken -- you just can't use it for web :/. If you were just scoping your app down for only android and ios I would suggest you use the older method (expo-google-app-auth). If I find a fix I'll report back here.

Answer (score 8):

So it's possible to get the idToken if you that's all you are looking for. You need to modify your code like this:

```js
     const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest({
        *responseType: "id_token",*
        expoClientId: 'my-expo-id',
        iosClientId: 'my-ios-id',
      });
```

You will also have to access the "params" key rather than "authentication," which will show mostly null :). For me it works at least since the rest of the information was useless. HTH!

Edit: I realized that I need to get an Access Token to use google drive in my app, and thus now I need both tokens and submitted a bug report here https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/12808 to try to get this resolved.

Comment: How did you get this information? I was having the same problem and spent an entire day searching for this, I only found it here. Thanks by the way, you saved me!

Comment: You are welcome. A lot of it just searching things that are tangential to the problem so instead of just looking for the Google endpoint, I searched up authSessions in general and with that there were enough examples. At certain points, I'm also just reading github docs (fyi there is another function called useIdTokenAuthRequest insead of useAuthRequest that isn't well documented but it does the exact same thing as adding in responseType-- and I only found that in the github code)

Comment: BTW thanks for the shoutout on github @fermmm haha

Comment: Is there also a similar way, so that a refresh token will be included?

Comment: not that I know of -- but I haven't taken a look in 2 years

Answer (score 2):

You can get user details like this:

1. First, get the access token from the response:

   `const accessToken = response.authentication.accessToken`
2. Send GET request to the following endpoint with the accessToken you obtained in step 1:

```
axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?
access_token='+ACCESS-TOKEN-HERE)
    .then(function(response){
        const userDetails = response.data
        console.log(userDetails)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add here that the id_token (Google-issued id_token) mentioned in howard's answer is a JWT that you can be decoded at jwt.io or using a jwt-decode library like jwt-decode (https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode) or doing something like this:

```
      import { Buffer } from "buffer";
      // get response object 
      const id_token = response.params.id_token;

      // need to decode the id_token(jwt) to get the user object, jwt issued by Google
      const jwt_parts = id_token
        .split(".")
        .map((jwt_part) =>
          Buffer.from(
            jwt_part.replace(/-/g, "+").replace(/_/g, "/"),
            "base64"
          ).toString()
        );
      const user = JSON.parse(jwt_parts[1]); // get user object after jwt decoded
      console.log(user);
```

user will then have these attributes:

```
interface GoogleUserFromJWTPayload {
  iss: string;
  azp: string;
  aud: string;
  sub: string;
  hd: string;
  email: string;
  email_verified: boolean;
  nonce: string;
  name: string;
  picture: string;
  given_name: string;
  family_name: string;
  locale: string;
  iat: number;
  exp: number;
  jti: string;
}
```

But if you need both id_token and accessToken in one go, as for now it still remain as an issue/limitation?:
https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/12808