# How to get user email using Google Sign In expo Auth Session?

Tags: react-native, email, expo, google-signin

At moment im using this snippet of code to sign in to google, but i cant get user email… anyone know how to do this?

```
var LoginGoogle = () => {

  const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest({

    androidClientId: 'xxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',

    expoClientId: 'xxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com'

  },{

    scopes: ["email"]

  },{});

  

  React.useEffect(() => {

    if (response?.type === 'success') {

      const { authentication } = response;

      console.log(response);

      }

  }, [response]);

  return (

    <GoogleSocialButton disabled={!request} onPress={() => {promptAsync()}} />

  ) 

}
```

response returns object with links instead of email

Answer (score 8):

I wish this is written in the expo docs. I would like to add a few points from the first answer:

1. First if you need code snippets on how to fetch user data after getting the access token, you can refer to this github issue: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/8384

access token can be received by the following code after receiving the response object:

```
const { authentication: { accessToken } } = response;
```

then, you can create a function like this:

```
async function fetchUserInfo(token) {
  const response = await fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
  });

  return await response.json();
}
```

and get the user object (which contains the user email, profile, photo, etc)  by something like this inside an async function:

```
const user = await fetchUserInfo(accessToken);
```

2. But NOTE for the user object, using https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo and https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo, will yield slightly different result/object ; in particular for v3, since Google implements the OpenID Connect API, there is no "id" attribute anymore, "id" will be called "sub".

sources:

- [How to identify a Google OAuth2 user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311836/how-to-identify-a-google-oauth2-user)
- https://developers.google.com/assistant/identity/google-sign-in-oauth
- https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/8384

Example of a user object in v3:

```
Object {
  "email": "xxxxx@gmail.com",
  "email_verified": true,
  "family_name": "John Deer",
  "given_name": "John",
  "hd": "gmail.com",
  "locale": "en",
  "name": "John Deer",
  "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/asdfjasdklfjaslkf",
  "sub": "10998837733652322",
}
```

Hope this helps someone in the future...!

EDIT: if you need the id_token checkout this one:
[expo-auth-session/providers/google Google.useAuthRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66966772/expo-auth-session-providers-google-google-useauthrequest/70040385#70040385)

Comment: Good answer. Thanks for linking to sources!

Answer (score 6):

I am using AuthSession as well in my RN app and I stumbled with this problem. After going through Google API Docs, found out you can pass the access token from the useAuthRequest response to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?access_token= **ACCESS_TOKEN**.

Comment: Well, I am really grateful for the Expo team for the APIs they provide to us for easy authentication in React Native. However, it would be great if they could give a slight hint to inform us that we need to visit the individual docs page of the provider to proceed. Or did I miss it out ;/, thanks for your answer anyway!

Comment: May I ask which documentation did you get this link from?