# I can not get tokenID when using google sign-in with react native

Tags: react-native, mobile, google-signin

I always get "undefined" value on idToken when i trying get it. Im using Google Cloud and Google Sign-in.
Here my code and the problem.  I don't know where this problem comes from, please help me!
My code here:

[image]
My problem:

[image]

I tried to find out and fix it in many ways but all ways can't get value in idToken

Comment: Does this answer your question? [expo-auth-session/providers/google Google.useAuthRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66966772/expo-auth-session-providers-google-google-useauthrequest)